# Comparing Computer Science masters

Tags: masters, computer-science, bachelor

I am currently planning to finish my bachelor degree in CS soon (In the Netherlands, if it matters). Unfortunately for the last few years I have had the feeling that my current university is lacking in the level of education compared to other universities.

This is mostly caused by the fact that when I search information about courses (e.g. slides on a subject which I don't fully understand yet, or information I search purely out of personal Interest) they often contain far more information and knowledge than that what was taught to us.

Due to this, I am currently looking to compare CS Majors. On one website, I found they had rankings based on various factors, yet it made me doubt some of the items taken into the ranking there.

I personally would like to learn more about certain aspects of computer science such as the design and architecture relating more complex applications, yet at the same time feel that the masters that my current university offers are not challenging enough for me. In addition, most of the top universities seem extremely expensive (Though some Canadian ones seem do-able without the international fee).

How do I compare computer science master studies and find the good ones?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia.SE!  I'm a bit confused by your question: one the one hand, you ask *whether* to take a master course (which we strangers on the internet cannot judge for you), and on the other hand you ask how to rank programs (which we might be able to help with).  I would suggest that you edit your question to focus on the ranking, and then the answers you receive may help you with your decision.

Comment: @jakebeal correct, i am still a bit in doubt (also due to age, I would be 28 before finishing mu masters which might make me old to start a job. Regardless I shall adjust the question.

Comment: I know this isn't addressing your question, but if your current Masters isn't challenging enough for you, have you considered trying to learn the extra material on your own? A ton of Universities have their material online and you sound motivated enough to be able to do it on your own.